# Why shouldn't I create an AUTOLOAD subroutine in the UNIVERSAL package?

Tags: perl, autoload, universal

My gut says this is a really bad idea, but I can't pin down a specific problem with it.  What follows is a very primitive implementation of mixins/traits using an AUTOLOAD subroutine in the UNIVERSAL package.  In terms of [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) answers, the right answer is to use [Moo](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Moo/lib/Moo.pm), but the person I am talking to doesn't want to use non-Core modules for some pointless reason and I want to convince them that this approach, while technically possible, is a bad idea, so I need technical reasons why this approach is a bad idea besides a queasy feeling.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

{
    package UNIVERSAL;

    sub with {
        my ($class, @mixins) = @_;

        our %mixin_map;

        push @{ $mixin_map{$class} }, @mixins;
    }

    sub AUTOLOAD {
        our $AUTOLOAD;

        # Never propagate DESTROY methods
        return if ($AUTOLOAD =~ /::DESTROY$/);

        my ($class, $method) = $AUTOLOAD =~ /(.*)::(.*)/;

        my @mixins = do {
            our %mixin_map;
            @{ $mixin_map{$class} };
        };
        for my $mixin (@mixins) {
            # find the mixin/trait that supports this method
            if (my $sub = $mixin->can($method)) {
                { #install the mixin's method in the class
                    no strict "refs";
                    *{ "$class::$method" } = $sub;
                }
                # call this class's method with the original arguments
                return $class->can($method)->(@_);
            }
        }

        use Carp;

        Carp::croak("could not find a method $method for class $class\nlooked in:", join ", ", @mixins);

    }
}

{
    package T;


    T->with(qw( Init Misc ));
}

{
    package A;

    A->with( qw/Init Helper/ );
}

{
    package Init;

    sub new {
        my ($class, $hParams) = @_;

        return bless {}, $class;
    }
}

{
    package Helper;

    sub foo {
        my ($self) = @_;
        print "foo here\n";
    }
}

{
    package Misc;

    sub something {
        my ($self) = @_;
        print "and more...\n";
    }
}

{
    package main;

    my $t = T->new;

    my $a = A->new;

    $a->foo;
    $t->something;

    eval {
        $t->foo;
        1;
    } or do {
        print "yay! calling foo on t failed\n";
    };

    eval {
        $a->something;
        1;
    } or do {
        print "yay! calling somehting on a failed\n";
    };
}
```

Comment: Why not just import the mixins when you call `with`?

Comment: what happens when you want to use UNIVERSAL::AUTOLOAD for this and someone else wants to use it for something else?

Comment: @ysth, AUTOLOAD is namespaces other than UNIVERSAL should chain, and AUTOLOAD is UNIVERSAL should wrap. Unfortunately, I suspect very few do.

Answer (score 3):

Problems:

- When you install an `AUTOLOAD`, you should create a corresponding `can`.
- Breaks any existing `UNIVERSAL::AUTOLOAD`.
- Adds a `with` to all classes.
- Broken by most other `AUTOLOAD`.

Some are fixable, some are not. But it shows how complex and fragile this is. And it's completely needless. `with` could import the methods, or it could simply adds the classes to `@ISA`.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can come up with is that UNIVERSAL::can won't work properly until the method is called for the first time.

Comment: When you create an `AUTOLOAD`, you also create a `can`. This is a bug in the OP's implementation, not a limitation.